# PostgreSQL 10 on Linux - LC_COLLATE locale en_US.utf-8 not valid

Tags: postgresql

> ERROR: invalid locale name: "en_US.utf-8"

Running Ubuntu server 18.04 Beta 2 with PostgreSQL 10.

In running a database creation script that worked on 9.5, I am now seeing an issue with 'en_US.UTF-8' as a locale:

```
CREATE DATABASE db WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

I know this may be redundant as I understand the default to be 'en_US.etf-8'.  Removing the LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE parameters let me run my script.

So did the locale definitions change somehow for V 10?  Or is there something else now happening?  I couldn't find anything on this in the Postgres 10 manual.

Comment: exact error please. It looks more ubuntu issue, but first - share exact error

Comment: The error is  ERROR:  invalid locale name: "en_US.utf-8"

Comment: I have verified I get the same error for LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE independantly (by specifying each by itself).  I noticed that the 'locale' response in 18.04 indicates the setting of C.UTF-8.  So maybe this is a conflict of some type?  Using C.UTF-8 in the SQL script triggers the same error 'invalid locale name'.

Comment: When I do create the database (without the locale spec) and I get to the interactive psql prompt, an \echo `$LC_CTYPE` (with tick quotes) returns a blank.  Not sure how sort collation is actually being handled without the spec.

Comment: check for available locales?.. `locale -a` if not found, try `locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Thanks Vao.  Locale -a only showed the C. responses.  The locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 did the trick.  I didn't realized this was needed.  So separately do I need to somehow set 18.04 to use this as the default instead of C.UTF-8 or would this not matter?  I would think it would not effect the database but could this cause problems elsewhere?

Comment: I'm not good with OS, but I assume yes - anything relying on right locale should fail without it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

check for available locales with `locale -a` if not found, try manually adding it with:

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

after this

```
CREATE DATABASE db WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

should work

Comment: I found that it wasn't really working as expected after running through the output of my script.  After adding the en_US.UTF-8, locale -A reports this as en_US.UTF8 (without the -).  I had to update the SQL script accordingly.

Comment: ERROR:  invalid locale name: "en_US.UTF-8"

Comment: I found that a restart (`sudo service postgresql restart`) was necessary before it would work.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same error, I generated the new locale:

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

I verified with `locale -a` that it was in fact present, then I logged out just to make sure, but I was still getting the same error on the database creation.

Finally, I solved the error by simply restarting the postgresql server with:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

After that, the database creation command was working!

Answer (score 6):

It's been performed on kubuntu and works perfectly, with some additional steps previously mentioned above, the right steps should be:

1. Validate the existence; if it doesn't exist, proceed to create it (will require sudo privileges)

   ```
   locale -a  |grep -i 'es_ES.utf-8'
   sudo locale-gen es_PE.UTF-8
   ```
2. Validate if the locale was created.

   ```
   locale -a|grep -i es
   es_ES.utf8
   es_PE.utf8
   ```
3. After the creation of the locale proceed to restart the postgres service, otherwise u will be getting the following error :

   ```
   ERROR:  invalid locale name: "es_ES.UTF-8"
   ```
4. Restart the postgres service

   ```
   systemctl restart postgresql
   ```
5. Finally, database was created.

   ```
   postgres=# create database db_izipay_prod with template=template0 encoding='utf8' lc_collate='es_ES.UTF-8' lc_ctype='es_ES.UTF-8' owner=postgres;
   CREATE DATABASE
   ```

Answer (score 5):

For me helped the next steps:

```
1. sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"

2. sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

3. sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

I don't why, but locale-gen not work.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error in a docker container. Here is how I solved it non interactively.

```
RUN echo "en_US UTF-8 " >> /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on Ubuntu server 18.04 with PostgreSQL 14, while trying to run a Django project doing the following:

```
# create new db with the above created user as its owner
createdb -E UTF8 --lc-collate=en_IN.UTF-8 --lc-ctype=en_IN.UTF-8 -T template0 -O <new_user_name> -U <root_user> <new_db_name>
```

The error I got was:

> createdb: error: database creation failed: ERROR:  invalid locale name: "en_IN.UTF-8"

I did following to solve it:

`locale -a` to see the list of locales which was missing "en_IN.UTF-8"

`sudo locale-gen en_IN.UTF-8` to generate the new locale

For me, it did not work without sudo.

Finally, run `sudo service postgresql restart`