# postgresql 11 - create database with ICU locale

Tags: postgresql, locale, collation, icu, postgresql-11

I want to use an ICU system-insensitive sorting collation, to avoid sorting differences between postgres11-on-mac vs postgres11-on-Ubuntu.  My first test was to dump out my existing `Collate=en_US.UTF-8` and pg_restore them into a db created with `Collate=en-US-x-icu`

[Create Database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createdatabase.html) doc has this to say:

> To create a database music with a different locale:
>
> CREATE DATABASE music
>       LC_COLLATE 'sv_SE.utf8' LC_CTYPE 'sv_SE.utf8'
>       TEMPLATE template0;

#### I seem to have the required icu locales already:

`select collname, collprovider  from pg_collation where collname like 'en_US%';`

```
        collname        | collprovider
------------------------+--------------
 en_US.UTF-8            | c
 en_US                  | c
 en_US.ISO8859-15       | c
 en_US.ISO8859-1        | c
 en_US                  | c
 en_US                  | c
 en-US-x-icu            | i 
 en-US-u-va-posix-x-icu | i 
(8 rows)
```

But no luck when creating a database with either icu locales.

```
CREATE DATABASE test LC_COLLATE = 'en-US-x-icu' TEMPLATE template0;
ksysdb=# CREATE DATABASE test LC_COLLATE = 'en-US-x-icu' TEMPLATE template0;
ERROR:  invalid locale name: "en-US-x-icu"
```

#### I can use `LC_COLLATE` with other locales:

The `LC_COLLATE` clause does seem to come with some strings attached, such as watching your encoding and specifying an appropriate template.  But it seems to give error hints w non-ICU locales.

This works, for example: `CREATE DATABASE test LC_COLLATE = 'en_US' TEMPLATE template0;`

and this one gives a helpful user message:

```
ksysdb=# CREATE DATABASE test LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.ISO8859-15' TEMPLATE template0;
ERROR:  encoding "UTF8" does not match locale "en_US.ISO8859-15"
DETAIL:  The chosen LC_COLLATE setting requires encoding "LATIN9".
```

Note:  a related question, [PostgreSQL 10 on Linux - LC_COLLATE locale en_US.utf-8 not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783108/postgresql-10-on-linux-lc-collate-locale-en-us-utf-8-not-valid), doesn't seem all that relevant, as the answer talks about generating an OS-level locale to fix the issue.  While the ICU locales, as far as I understand, are expressly intended to be separated from the underlying OS.

Comment: Currently you can't use ICU locales as the default locale

Comment: so.... specify it via ALTER COLUMN only?  or at CREATE TABLE time?  And is this also true on postgresql12, even though the question is for 11 right now?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: if you write it up and link to some postgresql doc, so that people can see when/if the restriction is lifted, I'll accept.

Comment: The only documentation is the source: `check_locale` in `src/backend/utils/adt/pg_locale.c` uses `setlocale` to check if the locale name is valid. That is a C library function, consequently it will only work with C library collations.

Comment: This seems to be a feature of the commercial 'EDB Postgres Advanced Server'. It seems you can set default ICU collations per database like `CREATE DATABASE collation_db TEMPLATE template0 ENCODING 'UTF8' ICU_SHORT_FORM = 'AN_CU_EX_NX_LROOT';` and even per cluster via `initdb --icu-short-form`. Nice examples in the [old docs](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/edb-postgres-advanced-server/user-guides/user-guide/9.6/EDB_Postgres_Advanced_Server_Guide.1.24.html#pID0E0TCD0HA).

Comment: Over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59168841 a nice conversion script is given to convert all text columns to icu collations.

Comment: Is this still true for version 15?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible from PostgreSQL v15 on:

```
CREATE DATABASE test
   LOCALE_PROVIDER icu
   ICU_LOCALE "en-US"
   LOCALE "en_US.utf8"
   TEMPLATE template0;
```

You still need to provide the libc locale, but the ICU library is used for collations.

Comment: This doesn't work in PG16. I guess you should skip `LOCALE` completely. The docs "locale [...] Can be overridden by setting lc_collate, lc_ctype, or icu_locale individually." https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createdatabase.html

Comment: @Nux Oh yes, that works in PostgreSQL v16. But perhaps your PostgreSQL is built without ICU support, or the C library locales have a different name on your operating system.

Comment: I have a fresh install of PG 16.2 on Ubuntu and it doesn't work. It does work when I remove `LOCALE "en_US.utf8"`.

Comment: @Nux As I said, that C library locale does not exist on your system. Run `locale -a` in your shell.

Comment: dpkg says otherwise (`dpkg -l | grep libicu`). I have `libicu66:amd64` "International Components for Unicode". If I use bogus `ICU_LOCALE` it fails, but this works fine: `CREATE DATABASE "test_mlnet1"
 WITH OWNER = molnet
 LOCALE_PROVIDER icu ICU_LOCALE "pl-PL"
 TABLESPACE = pg_default TEMPLATE template0
;`

Comment: @Nux Then look at `\l` and see what C library locale you got.

Comment: I did. You might want to check my answer. ICU should not depend on the system. That is the whole point AFAIK. And so far it seem to work as advertised :)

Answer (score 0):

### PG15 and later

From PG16 (at least in version 16.2) you might want to skip "LOCALE" all together.

This will work fine and should be enough:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE temp_test
LOCALE_PROVIDER icu ICU_LOCALE "pl-PL" TEMPLATE template0;
```

[image: Postgres 16.2 on Ubuntu]

This is how you can test that the ICU_LOCALE actually works and override collation:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    text_column VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO table1 (text_column) VALUES ('Zażółć');
INSERT INTO table1 (text_column) VALUES ('Abecki');
INSERT INTO table1 (text_column) VALUES ('Ącki');
INSERT INTO table1 (text_column) VALUES ('definicja');
INSERT INTO table1 (text_column) VALUES ('Żółć');
INSERT INTO table1 (text_column) VALUES ('<nieokreślony>');


SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY text_column;
```

Expected order (notice how national characters are mixed in):

- <nieokreślony>
- Abecki
- Ącki
- definicja
- Zażółć
- Żółć

Note that - quite confusingly - a database listing might show a different collation. But the test above shows that the collation is in fact provided by ICU (the listing is from PGv16.2, this might change in future).
[image]

### PG10 up to PG15

I should mention that for PG version 10 (and later) this would work, but only works on Windows:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE "temp_test"
    ENCODING 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE 'pl-PL-x-icu'
    LC_CTYPE 'pl-PL-x-icu'
    TEMPLATE template0
;
```

On Linux and Mac OS you would have to use the `COLLATE` keyword on each column separately:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    text_column VARCHAR(255) COLLATE "pl-PL-x-icu" NOT NULL
);
```

So updating to Postgres version 15 or later is advised if you want to have a consistent sorting on each operating system.

Comment: I don't know if that's so great, because you ended up with the default C library locale from the shell, which happened to be British English. So you would get for example an English decimal separator for `to_char(12.34, '99D99')`, which may not be what you want. It would have been better to explicitly specify `"pl_PL.UTF-8"` for `LOCALE` (note the spelling).

Comment: The spelling of utf8 is not problem. It still fails: ERROR:  invalid LC_COLLATE locale name: "pl_PL.UTF-8"; HINT:  If the locale name is specific to ICU, use ICU_LOCALE.

Comment: Since you are on Debian/Ubuntu: `sudo locale-gen pl_PL.utf8`. Then restart PostgreSQL and run `SELECT pg_import_system_collations('pg_catalog');`. Then you'll have the locale.

Comment: The app I develop is multilingual and formatting is done in the application, but that does seem to work. Kind of weird that formatting still relays on system components in PG.

Comment: Open source projects tend not to reinvent the wheel. We write a database server, and the resources are limited.